# API call to check if running in emulator wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a method I can call to see if I am currently running in the emulator vs. running on an actual physical phone?

I need to run some code a bit differently when I am in the emulator (I have a mock gps location service).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get this from Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType

Comment: if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == Microsoft.Devices.DeviceType.Emulator)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (System.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
{

}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

For wp 7.5 Mango sdk, it has moved to the namespace Microsoft.Devices

```
if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator)
{
  //Do Stuff
}
```